# gcc and explicit 256B boundary alignment on ARM

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, alignment

I'm using gcc toolchain for ARM and I need a linker to place a structure on a 256B boundary in memory. I've tried the aligned attribute:

```
volatile struct ohci_hcca hcca __attribute__ ((aligned (256)));
```

but with no luck:

```
nm out.elf | grep hcca
20011dc0 B hcca
```

I remember using this in past for fields that had to be on 512B boundary so I know it's possible but I seem to be missing something this time.

Thanks for any guidance.

**EDIT:**
The mystery's been solved. The BSP library is composed from tens of drivers and one of their header files contaned this:

```
#if defined __ICCARM__ || defined __CC_ARM || defined __GNUC__
//#pragma data_alignment=8   /* IAR */
#pragma pack(1)            /* IAR */
#define __attribute__(...) /* IAR */
#endif                     /* IAR */
```

For __GNUC__ it doesn't make any sense unless the author of this chunk is a member of guerrilla force against GCC users. Ruined my entire evening :)